# Perform a task on uninstall in android

Tags: android, uninstallation

I have developed an Android app. 
Now I want to perform a few operations (i. e. - Reset the settings etc.. ) at the moment the app gets uninstalled from the phone.

Is it possible to reigster a listener or a function that is called at the moment the app is removed?

Comment: The application `NQ Mobile Security` is calling an Activity at uninstall look at the http://i.imgur.com/Fos9N.png, http://i.imgur.com/fIZbK.png, http://i.imgur.com/cG9Hr.png and the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219328/how-to-show-an-activity-before-my-app-is-uninstalled-android

Comment: Check my answer at :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132472/can-code-be-called-when-my-android-application-is-uninstalled/28209337#28209337

this will help you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sadly android at the moment does not give you a possibility to perform code at the moment your app is uninstalled.

All the settings that are set via the SharedPreferences are deleted together with everything in the Application Data an Cache folder.

The only thing that will persist is the data that is written to the SD-Card and any changes to phone settings that are made. I don't know what happens to data that is synchronized to the contacts through your app.

Comment: I don't think its sad. In fact, I am elated, because it helps prevent spyware-like activity on my phone.

Comment: But it also prevents me from cleaning up certain things like the data I downloaded to SD-Card to prevent the phone memory from filling up. No I fill up the SD-Card. Maybe this will get better with app to sd in froyo but for devices under 2.2 I would like to be that polite on a uninstall.

Comment: @Janusz: Take a look at `getExternalStorageDirectory()` on the `android.os.Environment` class. The online doc says that has been there since API level 1, but I do not remember it. Regardless, that is supposed to give you an app-specific directory on the SD card that will be cleaned up when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: @dhaiwat - Time to accept your first answer. Go ahead, press the green checkbox, it won't bite.

Comment: This can be possible but i dont know how.In the market there is an application named as "Application Protector" who do this job. when user try to uninstall the application then user has to enter the password which is custom layout of the application.

Comment: The application `NQ Mobile Security` is calling an Activity at uninstall look at the http://i.imgur.com/Fos9N.png, http://i.imgur.com/fIZbK.png, http://i.imgur.com/cG9Hr.png and the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219328/how-to-show-an-activity-before-my-app-is-uninstalled-android

Comment: If it isnt possible then how Firebase Analytics provides app_remove events automatically?

Comment: @OfekRon of course it is possible to detect and google is doing it (sad for @BradHein) , but the question is whether the app can run code when it is being uninstalled.

Comment: What about  alarms set in `AlarmManager` ?

Answer (score 12):

You cannot get control when your application is uninstalled -- sorry!

Comment: thanks,
i set receiver for android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and it called when any application uninstall now how can i get package name which has been deleted on this receiver

Comment: If it isnt possible then how Firebase Analytics provides app_remove events automatically?

Comment: @OfekRon: Please do not post duplicate comments on multiple answers. I do not use Firebase, and I do not know what "app_remove events" are. However, *other apps* on the device can find out that your app was uninstalled. So, I would presume that the Play Services Framework app, the Play Store, or some other piece of Google proprietary code, is the one that is detecting the uninstall and forwarding that information to Google's servers.

Comment: @CommonsWare they are firebase analytics events. Google generates and shows you conversion statistics using those events. You can also generate custom events (with up to 500 different event types, I think)

Comment: Only thing you can do is to use any push notification service.

Answer (score 3):

Since API level 8 you may use Context.getExternalFilesDir().  In theory any data placed here will be removed when the application is uninstalled.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Answer (score -3):

When user uninstall android application in his mobile the  PACKAGE_REMOVED receiver will call. You can get uninstalled app package name use intent,getDataString()

```
if (intent.getAction (). equals ("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {
          String packageName = intent.getDataString ();
          System.out.println ("uninstall:" + packageName + "package name of the program");  
}
```

See complete example in this link.
http://foryouneed.blogspot.in/2014/08/android-listener-application-to-install.html

Comment: The app being uninstalled will not receive this Intent, from docs: 
"The package that is being installed does not receive this Intent". http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED