# How to know when user uninstall my app?

Tags: android

I need somehow to know which users uninstalled my android app and when.
I need it for install/uninstall reports.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132472/can-code-be-called-when-my-android-application-is-uninstalled/28209337#28209337

Comment: Most useful to know would be **why** do they uninstall your app.

Comment: You may use 'Google Play Developer Console Statistic' or 'Google Analytics API'.

Answer (score -1):

On the statistic section at the Google Play Developer Console, there is install/uninstall statistics. Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html#app-stats)

Comment: Will you explain this ?

Comment: You only want the statistics right?