# I want to delete contact group(created at installation time) at the time of my android application gets uninstalled in ANDROID

Tags: android, contacts

I have code to delete the contact group with the contact group id like this and is also working...

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();         
values.put(ContactsContract.Groups._ID, 4444);
getContentResolver().delete(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,values.toString(),null);
```

but I want to perform this deletion at the time of un-installation of the application in Android device.So what I have to do or which function can be used at uninstalling time?

So can you suggest me something?

Comment: Did you get control when your application un-installed? I don't think you can! If yes, then its nice to you for your efforts....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, **You cannot** get control or perform any task when your application is uninstalled.

Unfortunately there is currently no way for an Android package to execute code when it is removed. However, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` in a different package that will be called when packages are removed from the phone.

Look at this question [Perform a task on uninstall in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android)

Comment: I don't think so, BroadcastReceiver in different package is the only (some ugly) way. Thanks.