# Android uninstall application remove external data

Tags: android, apk, uninstallation

is there any way, when uninstalling application, that I also remove some data, which was used by that application? I mean some sort of onUninstall method?

Thanks

Comment: See my updated answer. See how it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Android (as of now) does NOT have any method like `onUninstall`. So there's no way you can run any code while uninstalling. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android) for more information.

However, you can use `createExternalStoragePrivateFile` and `getExternalFilesDir` methods to create an external file. Which will be deleted when your app is uninstalled.

Take a look at [docs and sample code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) from Android dev site.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of data you have to store in /data/data/ so that when the application is uninstalled the data of your app also removed. Your can use [Activity.getDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to get that folder.

Answer (score 0):

No,That will always remove data which stored in APK.

if you will store in sd card then it may be possible that you can get back but developer can also remove that data from any other location for security reason.

some time developer did not remove form sd card . so that you can get back and reuse again by your coding.

so,now its depends on you that where you are storing your data and how you will use them.

Comment: Thanks. I need to remove data from certain folder on SD card, when uninstalling my app. How?

Comment: when you storing your data @ that time you had write code as same you have to write code for remove data from their.

Comment: which type of data you want to store ?