# android push notification after user completely uninstall app

Tags: android, notifications, uninstallation

I wonder there is any way when user completely uninstall my app ,few days later a push notification asks user install new apps.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot perform operations after your app has been removed. Unfortunately there is currently no way for an Android package to execute code when it is removed. However, you can register a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for [`ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) *in a different package* that will be called when packages are removed from the phone.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android).

Comment: you mean, user must install 2 apps ,so that when user removes one , in the other app I can detect and perform some action?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way except the client has installed two of your apps. But however don't do that!