# Will android system consume memory for uninstalled applications too?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, stack, uninstallation

I'm uninstalling few applications from my android mobile, will those apps still occupy memory (or) is there any chance to have those app data in the android system memory?

If yes, how can we clear or how can we check that memory?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for RAM the answer is no, as the process ran your app is killed and the memory is freed, Also the shared preferences and sqllite databases you used in your app is also cleaned from your app memory space, but if you saved files during the time your app was active they are staying at the device internal storage or on the SD depends on where you put them.

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android) discusses that there is no onUninstall event callback you can register meaning you cant clean up after yourself...