# Delete folder from SD card when the app is deleted or uninstalled

Tags: java, android

I have tried to delete the my folder from the SD card when app is uninstalled, but I didn't find that the app is uninstalled. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform a task on uninstall in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android)

Comment: Could you add to your question any code that you have tried to get this working please.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is not need to do such a task.
Application specific files should be stored in an application directory.

You can get such a directory via [getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) or [getFilesDir ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()). There are some other dirs. Take a look at the [ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) class for more information.

The files inside these dirs will be deleted when the application is uninstalled.