# What happens in background when user uninstalls app

Tags: android, mobile

What are steps which happen when someone uninstall mobile app on iOS and android. Is there a way for developer to know that app is being uninstalled? I found about ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED in android but this isn't broadcasted to app being uninstalled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to detect Android app uninstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android

Comment: You can get the broadcast for any other app getting uninstalled but never for your own app.

Answer (score 0):

Your app, which is being uninstalled cannot receive the ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED broadcast.

You can use firebase analytics to know the details of uninstallation of your app. Check out the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/).

Comment: And how exactly?

Comment: @IulianPopescu everything is provided in the docs of firebase in the link I provided.

Comment: Where? I wasn't able to find how you can detect when you app is uninstalled?

Comment: The reports are seen automatically in the firebase console once you finish firebase integration in your app.

Comment: The link you provided simply directs to Firebase Analytics, no uninstall or something. Can you share please the exact link?