# Password request when uninstalling the application

Tags: xamarin.android

I want a way to put a password before uninstalling the application android 6 and higher.
Where if the password is added. The installation is don .
or canceled if there is no password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I **don't think** you can achieve this as you can't perform code at the moment your app is uninstalling.

Uninstalling the application is more like a system level action and you don't have permission to customize it.

Refer：

[Perform a task on uninstall in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android)

AND

[How can an app detect that it's going to be uninstalled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-can-an-app-detect-that-its-going-to-be-uninstalled)